# Call marker color in Geojson to apply to leaflet.js in php

Tags: leaflet, geojson, php

I have a geojson file which has marker-color properties in it.
In this case I want to call the marker color contained in the GeoJSON file, to change the marker color.
how to do this?

GeoJSON data:

```
    {
        "type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features":[
            {
                "type":"Feature",
                "properties":{"markercolor":"#1e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","title":"Indonesia"},
                "geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[107.9296875,-6.664607562172573]}
            },
            {
                "type":"Feature",
                "properties":{},
                "geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[114.873046875,4.565473550710278]}
            },
```

Leaflet php code:

```
L.geoJSON(data,{
   pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return new L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#7e7e7e",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
           
        });
    },
   
    onEachFeature:onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to feature properties inside your `poinToLayer` function through `feature` parameter, so you can reference your desired marker color with `feature.properties.markercolor`:

```
L.geoJSON(data,{
 pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
  return new L.circleMarker(latlng, {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: feature.properties.markercolor,
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  });
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

Comment: how to call marker-size from geojson file in leaflet.js?

Comment: You asked about setting marker color. Did the answer helped you solving your problem?

Comment: thank you, the answer is very helpful